# How to Bind rdlc report using business object?

Tags: c#, rdlc

i have business object called `"TeamMaster"`,
in which i define three properties,Id,Name & Flg.
in my .rdlc report i apply `TeamMaster` object as a data source,
now i write the following code in page load event of form in which i add report viewer control and i define my report as a local report.

```
using (RDLC_DEMO_DBEntities objdatabase = new RDLC_DEMO_DBEntities())
        {
            lstTeamMstr = objdatabase.TeamMasters.ToList();
        }
        this.TeamMasterBindingSource.DataSource = lstTeamMstr;
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

when i check this code using debugging i get 6 records in `TeamBindingSource`,
but in *windows report only displays six blank rows*,
what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this code : >>

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Your Report path);
ReportViewer1.Reset(); //important
ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Local;

// Add sub report even handler if you need  
***ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(MySubreportProcessingEventHandler);***
LocalReport objReport = ReportViewer1.LocalReport;
objReport.ReportPath = path;
// Add Parameter If you need 
List<ReportParameter> parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();
parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("Name", Value));
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);
ReportViewer1.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
ReportViewer1.ShowPromptAreaButton = false;
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();

//Add Datasourdce
ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
reportDataSource.Name = "Datasource Name Used due to report design";
reportDataSource.Value = DataSourceValue(Your object data-source);
objReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
objReport.Refresh();
```

Here Subreport Even handler code

```
private void MySubreportProcessingEventHandler(object sender,  SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
{
 //You can get parameter from main report 
int paramname = int.Parse(e.Parameters[0].Values[0].ToString());
//You can also add parameter in sub report if you  need like main report

//Now add sub report data source     
 e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSource Name",DataSourceValue)));
}
```

If you need to create Drillthrough report than follow this link [Click here for Drillthrough report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106376/calling-drillthrough-report-in-rdlc/10210131#10210131)